# erro na função count

Tags: python

A função `count` esta sempre mostrando o resultado `0`, alguém pode me ajudar?

```
nome = []
voto = []
aux = 1

while aux != 0:
    nome = str(input("Qual é o seu nome? "))
    aux = int(input("Qual é o melhor sistema operacional: Vote 1 pra Windows; Vote 2 para Linux; Vote 3 pra Mac Os; Vote 4 pra Outros: "))
    voto.append(aux)
    print( )

percentual1 = ([voto].count(1)) / len(voto)
percentual2 = [voto].count(2) / len(voto)
percentual3 = [voto].count(3) / len(voto)
percentual4 = [voto].count(4) / len(voto)

print("A quantidade de votos no total foi:", len(voto))
print("A quantidade de votos no Windows foi:", ([voto].count(1)))
print("A porcentagem de votos no Windows foi:", percentual1 * 100)
print("A quantidade de votos no Linux foi:", ([voto].count(2)))
print("A porcentagem de votos no Linux foi:", percentual2 * 100)
print("A quantidade de votos no Mac OS foi:", ([voto].count(3)))
print("A porcentagem de votos no Mac OS foi:", percentual3 * 100)
print("A quantidade de votos no Outros foi:", ([voto].count(4)))
print("A porcentagem de votos no Outros foi:", percentual4 * 100)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso está acontecendo por conta dos colchetes que colocou na variável `voto` antes de utilizar o `count`:

```
[voto].count(1)
```

Quando você faz isso, você acaba criando uma nova lista que contém `voto`, e ao chamar o método `count`, não encontra nenhum valor conforme o parâmetro informado.

---

Para corrigir, basta remover esses colchetes em todos os trechos que o fez:

```
voto.count(1)
voto.count(2)
...
voto.count(4)
```

Isso já vai corrigir o retorno do método `count`.

---

Porém perceba que quando é digitado `0` para sair do `while`, você inclui esse valor na lista `voto`:

```
voto.append(aux)
```

Com isso, mesmo que eu escolha apenas um sistema operacional, o percentual fica em 50%.

O ideal é que você não inclua zero ou até os demais valores que não consta pra você, caso queira que somente o zero não entre para os votos, faça um `if` antes de efetuar o `append` do valor:

```
if aux != 0:
  voto.append(aux)
```

Se deseja que somente os dados válidos sejam inseridos, você precisa criar uma condição diferente para o `if`, exemplo:

```
if aux > 0 and aux < 5:
  voto.append(aux)
```

---

Com isso seu código final vai ficar mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```
nome = []
voto = []
aux = 1

while aux != 0:
    nome = str(input("Qual é o seu nome? "))
    aux = int(input("Qual é o melhor sistema operacional: Vote 1 pra Windows; Vote 2 para Linux; Vote 3 pra Mac Os; Vote 4 pra Outros: "))
    print()

    if aux > 0 and aux < 5:
      voto.append(aux)

percentual1 = voto.count(1) / len(voto)
percentual2 = voto.count(2) / len(voto)
percentual3 = voto.count(3) / len(voto)
percentual4 = voto.count(4) / len(voto)

print("A quantidade de votos no total foi:", len(voto))
print("A quantidade de votos no Windows foi:", voto.count(1))
print("A porcentagem de votos no Windows foi:", percentual1 * 100)
print("A quantidade de votos no Linux foi:", voto.count(2))
print("A porcentagem de votos no Linux foi:", percentual2 * 100)
print("A quantidade de votos no Mac OS foi:", voto.count(3))
print("A porcentagem de votos no Mac OS foi:", percentual3 * 100)
print("A quantidade de votos no Outros foi:", voto.count(4))
print("A porcentagem de votos no Outros foi:", percentual4 * 100)
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/@Dadinel/ElementaryOrchidNanotechnology#main.py

---

> Documentação: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 3):

Você apenas fez uma confusão com a sintaxe das listas. Quando você vai chamar a mesma para consultar algum valor, como os votos para cada SO, não deve colocar o seu nome entre `[]`. Logo é só removê-los que vai funcionar:

```
nome = []
voto = []
aux = 1

while aux != 0:
    nome = str(input("Qual é o seu nome? "))
    aux = int(input("Qual é o melhor sistema operacional: Vote 1 pra Windows; Vote 2 para Linux; Vote 3 pra Mac Os; Vote 4 pra Outros: "))
    voto.append(aux)
    print( )

percentual1 = (voto.count(1)) / len(voto)
percentual2 = voto.count(2) / len(voto)
percentual3 = voto.count(3) / len(voto)
percentual4 = voto.count(4) / len(voto)

print("A quantidade de votos no total foi:", len(voto))
print("A quantidade de votos no Windows foi:", (voto.count(1)))
print("A porcentagem de votos no Windows foi:", percentual1 * 100)
print("A quantidade de votos no Linux foi:", (voto.count(2)))
print("A porcentagem de votos no Linux foi:", percentual2 * 100)
print("A quantidade de votos no Mac OS foi:", (voto.count(3)))
print("A porcentagem de votos no Mac OS foi:", percentual3 * 100)
print("A quantidade de votos no Outros foi:", (voto.count(4)))
print("A porcentagem de votos no Outros foi:", percentual4 * 100)
```

Answer (score 3):

As outras respostas já explicaram o seu erro, só gostaria de acrescentar um detalhe.

Chamar `count` várias vezes não é eficiente para o que você quer fazer, já que cada chamada de `count` percorre toda a lista para obter a contagem do elemento (ou seja, você está percorrendo a lista 4 vezes, desnecessariamente - em uma variação do [*Shlemiel the painter’s algorithm*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/)). Neste caso, uma opção melhor é usar um [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), que itera pela lista uma vez e já obtem a contagem de todos os elementos:

```
votos = []
opcoes = {
    '1': 'Windows', '2': 'Linux', '3': 'MacOS', '4': 'Outros'
}
texto_opcoes = '; '.join(f'Vote {i} para {desc}' for i, desc in opcoes.items())
while True:
    voto = input(f'Qual é o melhor sistema operacional: {texto_opcoes} (0 para sair):')
    if voto == '0':
        break
    elif voto in opcoes:
        votos.append(voto)
    else:
        print('Opção inválida')

from collections import Counter
c = Counter(votos)

print(f'A quantidade de votos no total foi: {len(votos)}')
for i, desc in opcoes.items():
    print(f'A quantidade de votos no {desc} foi: {c[i]}')
    print(f'A porcentagem de votos no {desc} foi: {c[i] * 100 / len(votos):.2f}%')
```

Como pôde perceber, também mudei outras coisas. Eu mudei o nome da lista que guarda os votos de `voto` para `votos`, pois se ela vai guardar mais de um voto, faz mais sentido que o nome esteja no plural. Pode parecer um detalhe besta e insignificante, mas [dar nomes melhores ajuda muito na hora de programar](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad).

Fiz um *loop* infinito (`while True`) para ir lendo as opções, e a opção de parada é quando o valor digitado é zero: neste caso, eu uso `break` para interromper o *loop*.

Coloquei as opções em um dicionário e usei as chaves como strings, assim você não precisa converter para `int` (pois se não for digitado um número, dará erro no programa). Até porque o fato das chaves serem números é circunstancial, e caso você queira mudá-las para outra coisa (por exemplo, "a" para "Windows", "b" para "Linux", etc), bastaria mudar as chaves do dicionário, e o restante do código permaneceria igual.

E eu uso o mesmo dicionário para mostrar as opções disponíveis, e também para mostrar as estatísticas.

---

Se bem que neste caso específico, como as chaves do dicionário são números sequenciais, eles também poderiam estar em uma lista. O que muda é que os índices são números e começam do zero, então você deve verificar se a conversão para `int` deu certo, e subtrair 1 ao guardar o voto (além de usar [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) para obter os índices ao iterar pela lista):

```
votos = []
opcoes = [ 'Windows', 'Linux', 'MacOS', 'Outros']
texto_opcoes = '; '.join(f'Vote {i + 1} para {desc}' for i, desc in enumerate(opcoes))
while True:
    try:
        voto = int(input(f'Qual é o melhor sistema operacional: {texto_opcoes} (0 para sair):'))
        if voto == 0:
            break
        elif 1 <= voto <= len(opcoes):
            votos.append(voto - 1)
        else:
            print('Opção inválida')
    except ValueError:
        print('Não foi digitado um número')

from collections import Counter
c = Counter(votos)

print(f'A quantidade de votos no total foi: {len(votos)}')
for i, desc in enumerate(opcoes):
    print(f'A quantidade de votos no {desc} foi: {c[i]}')
    print(f'A porcentagem de votos no {desc} foi: {c[i] * 100 / len(votos):.2f}%')
```